# Game of every user undefined, even if it should not be

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a Discord bot, which checks for the game a user is playing and auto assigns the fitting role. At the moment I am still figuring out how to get the game for the user. I managed to get a list of all users on the server, but it always says undefined for the game, even for people currently playing a game and displaying it on discord. I am not sure what exactly is the problem, as iI am pretty new to JavaScript.

My current code:

```html
client.on('ready', () =>{
    getAllUsersGames();
});

function getAllUsersGames(){
    
    var server = client.guilds.cache.get("Server-Id"); 

    var memberList = server.members;  
    memberList.cache.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username + " - " + member.user.presence.activities.name));
}
```

Comment: Specifically, which part says `undefined`?

Comment: Please share some sample data as to what `memberList` should look like

Comment: `paul5.0 - undefined
online509 - undefined
Terrifix - undefined
57 - undefined
D3SERT - undefined` and so on. The Usernames are alright, but i just cant get the game working.

Comment: @LearningEveryday It is essentially a list of member objects, which contains the matching properties like username and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: just use

```html
member.user.presence.activities
```

That would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that this line is an http GET request
`var server = client.guilds.cache.get("Server-Id");`
then you must use `async` function and `await` this request.

```
async function getAllUsersGames(){

    var server = await client.guilds.cache.get("Server-Id"); 

    var memberList = server.members;  
    memberList.cache.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username + " - " + member.user.presence.activities.name));
}
```

The reason you are getting undefined will be because the `console.log` is happening before the variable is populated with data from your request.

Comment: Well, sounds plausible, but I still get undefined for every user. Could there be another mistake in my code?

Comment: I'm not familiar with discord API, but I would probably debug and step through my code, try `console.log(member)` if `member === undefined` then problem is above if it's defined then the problem will be trying to access values in undefined keys.

Comment: It cant be member which is undefined, because the usernames work like a charm. But i think they changed how the game info works, because in all post i can find they are using member.users.game. In the documentation however there is not a single mention of a game property called game in user.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're having this issue is because [`activities`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=activities) returns an array of [`Activity`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Activity) so you could either loop through the array or you could just get the first activity using `activities[0]`